# Xcode 8 exit error code 1

Tags: xcode, swift2, swift3

I originally had Xcode 7 which I had then downloaded Xcode 8 which at that point the error exit code 1 occurs. I am not sure why this is happening. I think it has to do with swift 2 to swift 3 compiler differences.

[image: swiftc failed with exit code 1]

Comment: Have you cleaned the project?

Comment: I clean the project which removes the errors. I then run and build the project which then makes the error occur again.

Comment: Are you running on simulator or device?

Comment: I am running on the simulator for now.

Comment: try resetting your simulator. Go to Simulator in the top left, and hit reset content and settings.

Comment: I have never had to do that. How does one do that?

Comment: Well, the compiler complains about a file not being where I expects it, namely ".Item+CoreDataClass.swift" and ".Item+CoreDataProperties.swift" (Note the dot at the beginning). Maybe Xcode referenced them wrong?

Comment: No I had gotten rid of those files as I no longer need them. How do i fix Xcode from looking for those files?

Comment: Are they referenced in the project navigator (that thing on the left with all your files) or under your target build phases (Project -> Target (whatever the name of your target is) -> build phases (I think, not on a mac right now).

Comment: no they are not listed in the project navigator nor the compiler sources

Comment: Can I see the last file in which you have changed and this error occurs?

Comment: @matt2405 just to make sure: you did not only clean the project but also the build folder (option clicking on clean), right?